# How to get LifecycleOwner in LifecycleObserver?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components

I need to get the LifecycleOwner in an LifecycleObserver to pass it into an ViewModel observer.

This is my MainActivity, were I add the LifecycleObserver.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleOwner{

    private LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                    .commitNow();
        }

        mLifecycleRegistry=new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
        getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyLifecycleObserver());
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }

}
```

And this is my observere, where I need the LifecycleOwner.

```
public class MyLifecycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onStartListener(){

        FirebaseMassage.startFirebase();

        MainFragment.massageViewModel.getMassage().observe(/*here I need the LifecycleOwner*/, textMassage -> {
            FirebaseMassage.updateFirebaseMassage(textMassage);
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just use another signature to get the `LifecycleOwner` like:

```
public class MyLifecycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {


    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onStartListener(LifecycleOwner owner){
        ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: `@OnLifecycleEvent` is deprecated. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.4.0-beta01

Answer (score 4):

Observer methods can receive **zero or one argument**. If used(means you can go with zero argument too but **IFF** arguments are used), the first argument must be of type **LifecycleOwner**. Methods annotated with **Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY** can receive the second argument, which must be of type **Lifecycle.Event**.

```
class TestObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
         @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_CREATE)
         void onCreated(LifecycleOwner source) {
               //one argument possible
              }
         @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_START)
         void onCreated() {
              //no argument possible
             }
         @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_ANY)
         void onAny(LifecycleOwner source, Event event) {
             //two argument possible only for ON_ANY event
             }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a link where this is documented?

Comment: @pallgeuer https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#lc

Comment: Thanks. I was specifically looking for the documentation that the LifecycleOwner can optionally be passed as an argument to the function annotated with OnLifecycleEvent. Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: `@OnLifecycleEvent` is deprecated. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.4.0-beta01

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to implement your own LifecycleRegistry - just use the one available from AppCompatActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.container, MainFragment.newInstance())
                  .commitNow();
      }

      getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyLifecycleObserver());
  }
}
```

If you separate the startFirebase call and the viewmodel observer you can observe the changes from the viewmodel directly in the fragment, i.e.

MyLifecycleObserver starts the firebase call when ON_START is emitted.

```
public class MyLifecycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onStartListener(){
        FirebaseMassage.startFirebase();
    }
}
```

MainFragment observes the ViewModel directly.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
      massageViewModel.getMassage().observe(this, textMassage -> {
          FirebaseMassage.updateFirebaseMassage(textMassage);
      });
  }
```

Comment: `@OnLifecycleEvent` is deprecated. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.4.0-beta01

Answer (score 2):

Since `@OnLifecycleEvent` is deprecated, I believe the best approach would be to implement `LifecycleObserver` and override lifecycle methods:

```
class TestObserver: LifecycleObserver {

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onCreate(owner)
        // your code
    }

    override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onResume(owner)
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation of Abhishek Kumar's answer comes from here:

[https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle#subclasses-direct:~:text=Observer%20methods%20can%20receive%20zero%20or%20one%20argument](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle#subclasses-direct:%7E:text=Observer%20methods%20can%20receive%20zero%20or%20one%20argument)

Here is the document itself:

Observer methods can receive zero or one argument. If used, the first argument must be of type `LifecycleOwner`.

Methods annotated with `Lifecycle.Event.ON_ANY` can receive the second argument, which must be of type Lifecycle.Event.

```kotlin
 class TestObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
   @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_CREATE)
   void onCreated(LifecycleOwner source) {}
   @OnLifecycleEvent(ON_ANY)
   void onAny(LifecycleOwner source, Event event) {}
 }
```

Comment: `@OnLifecycleEvent` is deprecated. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.4.0-beta01